# mock Popen with pytest-mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest, popen

I have a Python module containing the following lines

```
import subprocess

# command that write things to a file in a specific location
command = 'default_command'

def f():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, ..some_args..)
    status_code = proc.wait()
    error_code = proc.stderr.read()
    # some stuff with status_code, error_code and the content of the file
```

The normal execution of `command` write things to a file and returns an exit code.

I want to write a unit test for that function with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) and [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/), which have to mock the `command` I execute with `Popen`. I need to mock that command because it has some not-well predictable output. The mock must do two things:

- Write some predictable output to the file
- Return a specific exit code and/or error code

How can achieve this?

Please let me know even if you think I'm taking a wrong approach to this.

Comment: `it has some not-well predictable output`, then the `command` program is to be teseted, why test the `f()`? If you are interested in testing the exit code related to `..some_args..`, then it is a different story, or the interest is only in parsing the output file.

Comment: Because `f()` is a Python wrapper to another program. I have to test the Python wrapper, not the other program

Comment: I would go for `mocker.patch('subprocess.Popen)` and the `wait()` and `read()`, get a test func to write a output you expected, but not sure it is even close to what you expect.